# How do I assign a struct array element to a temporary variable in C?

Tags: c, variables, struct

I have this testing code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Create struct
struct test
{
    int age;
};

// Create an array holding struct
struct test test_array[10];
int no_test = 0;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int i;

    // Take multiple inputs to assign to variables in struct
    while(no_test < 5)
    {
        // Create a temp struct instance to hold the current struct array element
        struct test temp = test_array[no_test];

        // Take input and feed it into the struct age
        scanf("%i", &temp.age);

        no_test++;
    }

    // Loop throgh struct and print out its values
    for (i = 0; i < no_test; i++){
        printf("Age: %i\n", test_array[i]);
    }
}
```

Currently, when I run this and input random 5 integers, the final print loop prints out `age=0` for all the elements in the array.

If I remove the `struct test temp = test_array[no_test];` line and point the scanf to `test_array[no_test]` instead, it works as expected, i.e the print loop prints the same values that were entered.

Is it possible to assign the line: `test_array[no_test]` to a variable (like a placeholder) as I will be using it a lot and I don't want to have to type it in every time.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a pointer. `struct test *temp = &test_array[no_test]; scanf("%i", &temp->age);`

Comment: @kaylum changed it to pointer and got this error: `error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int'). scanf("%i", *temp->age);`

Comment: Read the whole comment. What does my `scanf` look like compared to yours?

Comment: @kaylum my scanf: `scanf("%i", &temp->age);` and same got the same pointer statement as yours.

Comment: No it's not. That's not what the error msg says: `scanf("%i", *temp->age);`

Comment: ok the problem isn't in the scanf statement. It's in the print loop. When I comment out the loop, it compiles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231833/discussion-between-kaylum-and-slash).

Comment: Works now. I just hadn't saved the file before compiling it with @kaylum's code